# C printf prints two times after overfilling buffer with getchar()

Tags: c, printf, getchar

I need help with this simple code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    system("clear");
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter your name(MAX 24 chars) : ");
        char name[25];
        int x = 0;
        do {
            name[x] = getchar();
            x++;
        } while (x != 24 && !(name[x - 1] == '\n'));

        name[x - 1] = '\0';
        printf("Well it looks like your name is : %s\n", name);
    }
}
```

It works but it does one strange thing :

```
Enter your name(MAX 24 chars) : 123456789012345678901234567890
Well it looks like your name is : 12345678901234567890123
Well it looks like your name is : 567890
Enter your name(MAX 24 chars) :
```

When I overfill the `getchar()` with too many characters it does the `printf` line two times and prints the rest of it in next line.

My question is: Why is that ?

**EDIT**:
Answers are good but someone pointed out in comments that output is out of order. Why loop skips printf() ?

(I am also not a native so sorry for bad english)

Comment: Use the debugger to debug it. I mean at least try if you have not tried.

Comment: `while (x < 24) { int c = getchar(); if (c != '\n' && c != EOF) name[x++] = c; } name[x] = 0;` Adjust whether or not you include the `'\n'` in `name` as desired. (generally you won't).

Comment: If there are inputs that exceed the default number of characters, you need to (read and )discard them.

Comment: Are you sure the output was in that order? The second `Enter your name` prompt should appear before the second `Well it looks` line, for this code.

Comment: @M.M It is in order. Thats why I thought it is strange... I copied it from terminal

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the double print occurring in your code example has already been answered.  To *improve* the way user input is handled, consider using a combination of fgets and sscanf to read user input:

```
    char name[25]; 
    char c[25]; 

    printf("Enter your name(MAX 24 chars) : ");
    fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);//reads string input from stdin. into c, 
                               //including newline char.
    sscanf(c, "%s", name);//string 'c' is evaluated and parsed into 'name'.
                          //The %s format specifier, when used in sscanf,
                          //consumes white space, such as \n.
```

Comment: `fgets(c, 9, stdin);` ?? `if(fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin) == NULL) { ... }`

Comment: @WeatherVane - got it.  Thanks,  Edited.

Comment: The space in `" %24s"` will have the same result as `"%24s"`,  the space is not needed.  ``"%s"`` consumes leading white-space already.  In this case, the 24 is not needed either as `name` is the sufficient no matter the content of `c`.  Adding the space and 24 does no harm either except spin a few extra CPU cycles.

Comment: @chux - Thanks for pointing these out.  After re-reading about the %s specifier, I see your point about the space.  But regarding the width modifier, I am under the impression that it is _[always recommended](https://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm#scanfMatch)_ to avoid buffer overflow.  Can you explain why this is not true here?   (Click _See note_ in link for %s)

Comment: `name[]` has, at longest, a string of 24 characters and a null character.  `sscanf(c, "%s", name);` cannot overflow `c[]` as it has enough room for the longest string in `name[]`.  IMO, having a right sized buffer (like `char c[sizeof name];` is more variable than a width limited `sscanf()` - and easier to maintain.  Too often code uses width limits without addressing what to do with a incomplete string.  If pressed, one could do both:[belt and suspenders](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/belt_and_suspenders#Noun)

Comment: @chux - Thank you for your explanation. This is a cleaner approach,  I edited code and comments to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

> When I overfill the getchar() with too much characters it does the printf line two times and prints the rest of it in next line.
>   My question is: Why is that ?

When you read only a part of input, the remaining characters are still there in the input stream. So, when the outer loop continues, `getchar()` reads the remaining chars into `name`.

Using `fgets()` is generally better option but you'd still have the same problem with the "extra" input.

You can use a simple loop to consume any extra chars that might present in the input with (after the inner while loop):

```
int ch;
while((ch=getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the array by int x=0 so it is reprinting and it is an infinite loop. Here is explanation:

```
while(1){ // enter infinite loop 2nd time
    printf("Enter your name(MAX 24 chars) : ");
    char name[25]; //declare new array 2nd declaration
    int x=0;    //reset of loop counter 2nd reset
    do{
        name[x] = getchar();    // start reading 2nd time read from the stream
        x++;
    }while(x!=24 && !(name[x-1] == '\n'));   // stop reading but data is
                                             //in stream

    name[x-1] = '\0';   // end of string marker
    printf("Well it looks like your name is : %s\n",name); // print and
                                                //enter loop again
```

}

Comment: Where is the printf from the second line ? I mean anwser is good but there is no printf after the loop resets

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question is simple: the while loop is always true, so when you enter a name over than 24 characters, your program only scans maximum 24 characters, then prints the name and starts the next loop. since there exist characters that are not scanned in the previous loop, they are being scanned in the flow loop. the program won't ask for input because of existing characters.

if you debug the program, you can clearly see what is happening.